# Python tkinter create image with different layers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, tkinter

I would like to give layers to tkinter images when we created them below code:

```
from tkinter import *

canvas_width = 300
canvas_height =300

master = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(master, 
           width=canvas_width, 
           height=canvas_height)
canvas.pack()

mylist = []
img = PhotoImage(file="./Images/screwsmall.png")
mylist.append (canvas.create_image(20,20, anchor=NW, image=img))

img_2 = PhotoImage(file="./Images/screwsmall.png")
mylist.append (canvas.create_image(50,20, anchor=NW, image=img_2))

mainloop()
```

As you can see two images are created, however the second image is on top of first image. How can I decide their layers by the code? In other words can I make the first image go on top of other with out creating order?

[image]

Comment: yes you can use `canvas.lift(img)` or `canvas.lower(img_2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the tag_lower() and tag_raise() methods for the Canvas object:

```
canvas.tag_raise(mylist[0]) # move the first image to the top
```

Comment: As far as I see I can give layers to different tags. .tag_raise(tagOrId, aboveThis) thats nice.

Comment: Many things in tkinter work on the concept of tags, where you can assign a label to a group of things. In this case it's a group of 1, but you still use the same command to work with them.